# JQuery sliding drop menu not functioning in IE(10)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

I designed a .click drop-down menu using Jquery and it works great in Chrome, but it doesn't do anything in Internet Explorer(version 10 on my computer.) I have another fading gallery script on the same page that is working, so I can't figure out why the drop-downs aren't activating. I hope its just a rookie mistake on my part, and not some deeper embedded issue with the code i'm using. Any help is most appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/nZfSd/

CSS Styling ------------------------------------------

```
/*Drop-down Menu Styling*/
.make {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 110px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
.makewrap {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    }
.makeactive {
}

.model {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 110px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
    Color: #FFF;
    opacity: .8;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    }
.modelwrap {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 114px;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin-left: 20px;
    }
.modelactive {
}

.product {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    width: 150px;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    color: #000;
    Text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.productwrap {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 154px;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin-left:-20px;
}
.productactive {
}
/*drop-down menu styling end*/
```

HTML Code ------------------------------------------------

```
<div class="dropdownmenus">
<!--CLUB CAR Drop-down Begins Here-->
<ul class="makewrap">
<div class="make">CLUB CAR</div>

    <!--DS BEGINS HERE-->   
    <ul class="modelwrap" style="display: none">
    <div class="model">DS</div>

    <ul class="productwrap" style="display: none">
        <div class="product">Billet Accessories</div>
        <div class="product">Bodies</div>
        <div class="product">Brush Guards & Bumpers</div>
        <div class="product">Cargo & Storage</div>
        <div class="product">Chargers & Accessories</div>
        <div class="product">Covers & Enclosures</div>
        <div class="product">Diamond Plate</div>
        <div class="product">Hitches</div>
        <div class="product">Lift Kits</div>
        <div class="product">Lights & Accessories</div>
        <div class="product">Brakes & Performance</div>
        <div class="product">Replacement Parts</div>
        <div class="product">Seat Belts</div>
        <div class="product">Seat Kits & Cushions</div>
        <div class="product">Stainless Steel</div>
        <div class="product">Steering Wheels</div>
        <div class="product">Tires</div>
        <div class="product">Wheels</div>
        <div class="product">Windshields</div>
    </ul>

    </ul><!--DS ENDS HERE-->

    <!--PRECEDENT BEGINS HERE-->
    <ul class="modelwrap" style="display: none">
    <div class="model">PRECEDENT</div>

    <ul class="productwrap" style="display: none">
        <div class="product">Billet Accessories</div>
        <div class="product">Bodies</div>
        <div class="product">Brush Guards & Bumpers</div>
        <div class="product">Cargo & Storage</div>
        <div class="product">Chargers & Accessories</div>
        <div class="product">Covers & Enclosures</div>
        <div class="product">Diamond Plate</div>
        <div class="product">Hitches</div>
        <div class="product">Lift Kits</div>
        <div class="product">Lights & Accessories</div>
        <div class="product">Brakes & Performance</div>
        <div class="product">Replacement Parts</div>
        <div class="product">Seat Belts</div>
        <div class="product">Seat Kits & Cushions</div>
        <div class="product">Stainless Steel</div>
        <div class="product">Steering Wheels</div>
        <div class="product">Tires</div>
        <div class="product">Wheels</div>
        <div class="product">Windshields</div>
    </ul>

    </ul><!--PRECEDENT ENDS HERE-->

</ul>
<!--CLUB-CAR ENDS HERE-->

<!--E-Z-GO Drop Down Begins Here-->
<ul class="makewrap">
<div class="make">E-Z-GO</div>

    <!--TXT BEGINS HERE-->
    <ul class="modelwrap" style="display: none">
    <div class="model">TXT</div>

    <ul class="productwrap" style="display: none">
        <div class="product">Billet Accessories</div>
        <div class="product">Bodies</div>
        <div class="product">Brush Guards & Bumpers</div>
        <div class="product">Cargo & Storage</div>
        <div class="product">Chargers & Accessories</div>
        <div class="product">Covers & Enclosures</div>
        <div class="product">Diamond Plate</div>
        <div class="product">Hitches</div>
        <div class="product">Lift Kits</div>
        <div class="product">Lights & Accessories</div>
        <div class="product">Brakes & Performance</div>
        <div class="product">Replacement Parts</div>
        <div class="product">Seat Belts</div>
        <div class="product">Seat Kits & Cushions</div>
        <div class="product">Stainless Steel</div>
        <div class="product">Steering Wheels</div>
        <div class="product">Tires</div>
        <div class="product">Wheels</div>
        <div class="product">Windshields</div>
    </ul>

    </ul><!--TXT ENDS HERE-->

    <!--RXV BEGINS HERE-->
    <ul class="modelwrap" style="display: none">
    <div class="model">RXV</div>

    <ul class="productwrap" style="display: none">
        <div class="product">Billet Accessories</div>
        <div class="product">Bodies</div>
        <div class="product">Brush Guards & Bumpers</div>
        <div class="product">Cargo & Storage</div>
        <div class="product">Chargers & Accessories</div>
        <div class="product">Covers & Enclosures</div>
        <div class="product">Diamond Plate</div>
        <div class="product">Hitches</div>
        <div class="product">Lift Kits</div>
        <div class="product">Lights & Accessories</div>
        <div class="product">Brakes & Performance</div>
        <div class="product">Replacement Parts</div>
        <div class="product">Seat Belts</div>
        <div class="product">Seat Kits & Cushions</div>
        <div class="product">Stainless Steel</div>
        <div class="product">Steering Wheels</div>
        <div class="product">Tires</div>
        <div class="product">Wheels</div>
        <div class="product">Windshields</div>
    </ul>

    </ul><!--RXV ENDS HERE-->

    <!-- MARATHON BEGINS HERE-->
    <ul class="modelwrap" style="display:none">
        <div class="model">MARATHON</div>

        <ul class="productwrap" style="display: none">
            <div class="product">Diamond Plate</div>
            <div class="product">Lift Kits</div>
            <div class="product">Tires</div>
            <div class="product">Wheels</div>
        </ul>

    </ul><!--MARATHON ENDS HERE-->

    <!-- WORKHORSE BEGINS HERE-->
    <ul class="modelwrap" style="display:none">
        <div class="model">WORKHORSE</div>

        <ul class="productwrap" style="display: none">
            <div class="product">Diamond Plate</div>
            <div class="product">Stainless Steel</div>
            <div class="product">Tires</div>
            <div class="product">Wheels</div>
        </ul>

    </ul><!-- WORKHORSE ENDS HERE-->

</ul>
<!--E-Z-GO ENDS HERE-->

<!--YAMAHA Drop-down Begins Here-->
<ul class="makewrap">
<div class="make">YAMAHA</div>

    <!--G1 BEGINS HERE-->
    <ul class="modelwrap" style="display:none">
    <div class="model">G1</div>

    <ul class="productwrap" style="display:none">
        <div class="product">Lift Kits</div>
        <div class="product">Tires</div>
        <div class="product">Wheels</div>
    </ul>

    </ul><!--G1 ENDS HERE-->

    <!--G2/G9 BEGINS HERE-->
    <ul class="modelwrap" style="display:none">
    <div class="model">G2/9</div>

    <ul class="productwrap" style="display:none">
        <div class="product">Lift Kits</div>
        <div class="product">Tires</div>
        <div class="product">Wheels</div>
    </ul>

    </ul><!--G2/G9 ENDS HERE-->

    <!--G14/16/19 BEGINS HERE-->
    <ul class="modelwrap" style="display:none">
    <div class="model">G14/16/19</div>

    <ul class="productwrap" style="display:none">
        <div class="product">Body</div>
        <div class="product">Brush Guards & Bumpers</div>
        <div class="product">Cargo & Storage</div>
        <div class="product">Diamond Plate</div>
        <div class="product">Seat Kits & Accessories</div>
        <div class="product">Lift Kits</div>
        <div class="product">Tires</div>
        <div class="product">Wheels</div>
        <div class="product">Windshields</div>
    </ul>

    </ul><!--G14/16/19 ENDS HERE-->

    <!--G22 BEGINS HERE-->
    <ul class="modelwrap" style="display:none">
    <div class="model">G22</div>

    <ul class="productwrap" style="display:none">
        <div class="product">Body</div>
        <div class="product">Brush Guards & Bumpers</div>
        <div class="product">Diamond Plate</div>
        <div class="product">Seat Kits & Accessories</div>
        <div class="product">Lift Kits</div>
        <div class="product">Tires</div>
        <div class="product">Wheels</div>
        <div class="product">Windshields</div>
    </ul>

    </ul><!--G22 ENDS HERE-->

    <!--DRIVE BEGINS HERE-->
<ul class="modelwrap" style="display:none">
<div class="model">DRIVE</div>

    <ul class="productwrap" style="display:none">
        <div class="product">Brush Guards & Bumpers</div>
        <div class="product">Diamond Plate</div>
        <div class="product">Tire</div>
        <div class="product">Wheel</div>
    </ul>

     </ul><!--DRIVE ENDS HERE-->

</ul><!--YAMAHA ENDS HERE-->

</div><!--dropdownmenus div END-->
```

Jquery Script ----------------------------

```
//start of Drop down menu script
$("ul.makewrap").click(function () {
    $this=$(this)
    $makeactive=$('.makeactive')
    $modelactive=$('.modelactive')
    event.stopPropagation();
        if ($this.children('ul').is(":hidden")) {
            $makeactive.children('ul').slideUp("fast");
            $makeactive.children('div').css({"background-color": "#FFF", "color": "#000"});
            $modelactive.children('ul').slideUp("fast");
            $modelactive.children('div').css("background-color", "#2e2e2e");
            $this.children('ul').slideDown("fast");
            $this.children('div').css({"background-color": "#990000","color": "#FFF"});
            $this.addClass('makeactive');
        }
        else {
            $this.children('ul').slideUp("fast");
            $this.children('div').css({"background-color": "#FFF", "color": "#000"});
            $this.removeClass('makeactive');
        }
});

$("ul.modelwrap").click(function () {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $this=$(this)
    $modelactive=$('.modelactive')
        if ($this.children('ul').is(":hidden")) {
            $modelactive.children('ul').slideUp("fast");
            $modelactive.children('div').css("background-color", "#2e2e2e");
            $this.children('ul').slideDown("fast");
            $this.children('div').css("background-color", "#990000");
            $this.addClass("modelactive");
        }

        else {
            $this.children('ul').slideUp("fast");
            $this.children('div').css("background-color", "#2e2e2e");
            $this.removeClass("modelactive");
        }

});
$("ul.productwrap").click(function () {
event.stopPropagation();
});
//end of drop-down menu script
```

Comment: Consider changing your structure on your HTML.  While it's working, sematically HTML UL's require LI (or list items of an unordered list) to function.  The most w3 compatible solution to this layout is a UL with 3 li's for the top menu level, with UL's and LI's nested in each top-level LI for the sub menus.  You'd trigger your click (which would be better done with a $('selector').on('click', 'li)) and fire the sub menu using the object context, $(this)  Great start, hope you can continue to refine your script!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.click(function (event) {
//....
event.stopPropagation();

}
```

you missed to add `event` in all click event handler.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nZfSd/1/)

Comment: @ChristopherThrower Thanks I've added the fiddle in my answer.

Comment: @Mister-Green I'm glad I was able to help.